# json.parse and ajax was working ok. until when i set my database online

Tags: json

The json.parse method  was working fine . but when i host database in web hosting . it takes me

> JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

this is my code :

```
function getListProduitsByIdcat(id)
{

$j.get("/java 2015 v0/admin/code%20php/code_produits.php?idca="+id,function(data,status)
{       
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)

     list=[];
     list=JSON.parse(data);
     names=[];

   for(var j=0;j<list.length;j++)
    names.push(list[j].nom);

        $j("#produit").autocomplete({
        source: names,
        change: function(event,ui)
        {
          if(!ui.item){
                //http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change -
                // The item selected from the menu, if any. Otherwise the property is null
                //so clear the item for force selection
                $j("#produit").val("");
                $j("#produit").attr("placeholder","n'exist pas ");
            }  
        },
        focus: function (event, ui) {
              return false;
             }
    });
    }
);
}
```

Comment: Are you in chrome? Right click+inspect element, then goto "Network Tab". Click on "/java 2015 v0/admin/code%20php/code_produits.php?id" and look at what the preview shows. You a likely getting back some error outputted to the screen before you are echoing the JSON. Check it out there.

Comment: I've had issues using $.get before, where on some browsers wouldn't work. I don't know if this related. However, I chose to use $.ajax and specified contentType to json

Comment: thanks for replying ,
but that its happen in all browsers.
and this is the data which i got from the function:
{"id":"4","nom":"samsung","categorie":"2","description":" s4","prix_vente":"3000","duree_garantie":"7","nbpieces":"30"}

Answer (score 0):

The error is explicit, Json in `data` isn't a valid Json. Can you print the data content ?

But I see you didn't check `the status`, so you don't know if the `get` method have success or not.

The first `for` do anything ?

BTW, You have space in your url it's a mistake ?

```
/java 2015 v0/admin/code%20php/code_produits.php?idca=
```

Comment: i check it and its working good . and this is the data wich i got from the function: {"id":"4","nom":"samsung","categorie":"2","description":" s4","prix_vente":"3000","duree_garantie":"7","nbpieces":"30"}